# Should I use "can" or "could" in the phrase "If you don't challenge yourself you'll never realise what you can/could become"?

Tags: conditionals, could-modal

Should I use "can" or "could" in the phrase "If you don't challenge yourself you'll never realise what you can/could become"?

Is this an example of a conditional? And if so which type?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional. You can use either "can" or "could". I think it would be more correct to say "could have" than just "could" though. Those would both be right but the feeling that they suggest is slightly different. 'You'll never realize what you can become' puts a little more emphasis on your belief that your audience can become something great. 'You'll never realize what you could have become' puts a little more emphasis on your belief that your audience might waste their potential.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work. I'd recommend "can".

This is a very focussed, emphatic statement. "If you don't challenge yourself", followed by "you'll never realise". Note that the second clause is not something like "you might never realize". It is direct and forceful. To follow this with "what you could become" is much more tentative than "what you can become." In part this is because "can" expresses both possibility and determination, as in "You can do this."